# How to use jackson with lombok Builder to deserialize a json-array?

Tags: java, json, jackson, builder, lombok

I want to deserialize a primitive json-array into an Object.
That Object is annotated with lombok's value and builder annotation.
I can't get it to work:

The json looks like this:

`["btcusd","ltcusd","ltcbtc"]`

This is the call to get some json-array:

```
public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
  return args -> {
    Pair[] pairs = restTemplate
      .getForObject("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/symbols", Pair[].class);
    log.info("List[" + Arrays.stream(pairs).map(Pair::getPairId).collect(
      Collectors.joining(", ")) + "]");
  };
}
```

And this is the Pair.class

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Pair.PairBuilder.class)
public class Pair {
  @NonNull private String pairId;
  private String left;
  private String right;

  @Builder
  private Pair(String pairId) {
    this.pairId = pairId;
    left = pairId.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    right = pairId.substring(3).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
  }

  @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
  public static final class PairBuilder {
//    @JsonCreator
//    public PairBuilder pairID(@NonNull String pairId) {
//      this.pairId = pairId;
//      return this;
//    }
  }
}
```

I get this exception

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.rwest.bitcoinchecker.Pair$PairBuilder: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('btcusd')

Comment: When using 3rd party libraries (jackson, lombok) please provider imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already specified builder with lombok annotation, you don't have to create builder class yourself.

Working example:.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Pair[] pairs = restTemplate
        .getForObject("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/symbols", Pair[].class);
```

Pair class:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Value;

import java.util.Locale;

@Value
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Pair {
    @NonNull private String pairId;
    private String left;
    private String right;

    @Builder
    private Pair(String pairId) {
        this.pairId = pairId;
        left = pairId.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
        right = pairId.substring(3).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Pair(pairId=btcusd, left=BTC, right=USD)
Pair(pairId=ltcusd, left=LTC, right=USD)
Pair(pairId=ltcbtc, left=LTC, right=BTC)
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're trying to do it and suggest that you're doing it wrong, but your exception says that it's require constructor with String:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
```

when you set access to "PRIVATE" it's hide constructor from all external accessors, so remove from annotation "access" argument

Comment: That does not help - same error, no matter if I remove access or the whole annotation.

Comment: okay, you specified builder: Pair.PairBuilder.class - means inner class PairBuilder - must have constructor with String, but if you take a look at example with ``@JsonDeserialize``, you see that maybe you need some other  way of implementation this

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations